# explanation of a triple integral $\iiint _{x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2}\left|xz\right|y^2dxdydz\:$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to figure out how the my book solve this exercise:

$$\iiint _{x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2}\left|xz\right|y^2dxdydz\:$$

**BOOK SOLUTION:**

$$\iiint _{x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2}\left|xz\right|y^2dxdydz\: = 8\iiint _Sxzy^2dxdydz\:$$
with:
$$S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2, x\ge0, y\ge0, z\ge0\}$$
We transform in spherical coordinates:
$$S=\{(\rho,\phi,\theta): \rho \in [0,R], \phi\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}], \theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\}, dxdydz=\rho^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta d\rho$$
then, the exercise continues with the triple integral solution after the transformation (which is not difficult).

**MY DOUBT**

i will report below, what I am not clear (outlined in red)

$$\iiint _{x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2}\left|xz\right|y^2dxdydz\: = \color{red}{8\iiint_Cxzy^2dxdydz\:}$$
I just can not understand how these two integrals can be equal.

Then:
$$S=\{(\rho,\phi,\theta): \rho \in [0,R], \color{red}{\phi\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}, \color{red}{\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}\}, dxdydz=\rho^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta d\rho$$
why in that range?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know about the [octants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)) and even functions?

Comment: its the first time I see him, but I do not think may Useful for this integral, Otherwise the professor would have explained them

Comment: It is certainly useful for this integral to use that symmetry.

Comment: FYI, you can use `\iiint` in LaTeX syntax for triple integral, it's a little nicer looking. I edited your post to use it.

Comment: @6005 yeah i saw thanks

Comment: @mickep can you show me some  intermediate step, which leads That an equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_1&=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3~|~x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2\},\\
D_2&=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3~|~x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2,\ x\geq 0\}\\
D_3&=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3~|~x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2,\ x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0\}\\
D_4&=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3~|~x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2,\ x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0,\ z\geq 0\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, since your function $f(x,y,z)=|xz|y^2$ is even in all three variables,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\iiint_{D_1}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz
&=
2\iiint_{D_2}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz\\
&=
4\iiint_{D_3}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz\\
&=
8\iiint_{D_4}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz
\end{aligned}
$$
Moreover, in $D_4$ you have $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z$.

For the second question, in spherical coordinates the first octant satisfies the bound for the angles, i.e. $0\leq\phi\leq\pi/2$ and $0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$. Draw a picture and make sure you understand that.

Comment: so the abs disappears because all the variable are set greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And this is the reason you want to work in one octant in the first place.